# Writing the expectation with the help of integrals?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

In a book I saw that there are two conditions for a lemma:

1) $$\mathbb{E}\vert g(X_1,\ldots, X_m)\vert^r < \infty$$
and

2)$$\int \vert g(X_1,\ldots, X_m)\vert^r dF(X_1) \ldots dF(X_m) < \infty$$

here g is a permutation-symmetric function into the real numbers and with permutation symmetric I just mean: $$g(X_1, \ldots, X_i, \ldots, X_j, \ldots,X_M)=g(X_1, \ldots, X_j, \ldots, X_i, \ldots,X_M),$$ so we can just change the aruments among each other without changing the result;

But isn't (1) and (2) exactly the same? Isn't by definition given that? 
$$\mathbb{E}\vert g(X_1,\ldots, X_m)\vert^r=\int \vert g(X_1,\ldots, X_m)\vert^r dF(X_1) \ldots dF(X_m)$$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two conditions are identical only if $F(X_1,\cdots,X_n)=F(X_1)\cdots F(X_n)$, namely, that $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are independent. In other cases, the expectation and the integration are **not** the same.

Comment: Can't believe how I've been that blind -thank you